# Map string to a property in collection

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to solve seemingly trivial task. How to map string to a property of a collection? Bellow I show my current situation. I am trying to map the DeliveryType.UrlTemplate property of DeliveryNoteTableDto class to each PackageDto.UrlTemplate property. I am using AutoMapper. Currently I am getting error:

> Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type.

when performing the mapping. Any help?

classes

```
 public class DeliveryNoteTableDto
{

    public List<PackageDto> Packages { get; set; } = new List<PackageDto>();

    public DeliveryTypeDto DeliveryType { get; set; }  
}

  public class PackageDto
{
    public virtual string DeliveryKey { get; set; }

    public virtual string UrlTemplate { get; set; }
}

    public class DeliveryTypeDto
{
    public virtual string Transporter { get; set; }

    public virtual string UrlTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

mapping

```
map.ForMember(x => x.Packages.Select(p => p.UrlTemplate), opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.DeliveryType.UrlTemplate));
```

Comment: I'm confused - you want to use AutoMapper to project one property of a class to other properties _within the same class_?

Comment: Yes. That's what I thought of doing. Is there a better way how have the property populated when the object is initialized?

Comment: How is the object created/initialized?  You could do that in the constructor or in the setter of `DeliveryType` (which means you can't use an automatic property.

Comment: I'm really confused too. What are the set of source objects and destination objects?

Comment: Seems like I was even more confused than you. I was able to solve it by setting a getter. Thanks @DStanley